# Unusual pair of dice

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we roll two ordinary, 6-sided dice, $f_i=s_i=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $. 
All $36$ possible rolls with a pair of dice (first dice - $f_i$, second dice $s_i$):

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
   f_i/s_i & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
  2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
  3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
  6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 
\end{array}
$$

So we have $1$ variant to roll the sum $2,  2$ variants to roll $3, 3$ variants to roll $4, ..., 2$ variants to roll $11, 1$ variant to roll $12.$

Is there some another pair $(f_i, s_i)$ of $6$-sided dice with different numbers on its sides, but with the same set of variants to roll the same sums $(2,\ldots,12)$? And all $f_i>0, s_i>0$. And how much?

$f_i$ and $s_i$ in such pair can be different.

**Special upd** $f_i \in \mathbb{N}$, $s_i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.
If we factor the generating function $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^2$, we obtain 
$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^2= x^2(x+1)^2(x^2-x+1)^2(x^2+x+1)^2$$
and have the option of distributing the factors unevenly to the dice. But (apart from the standard dice) the *only* possibility to have nonnegative coefficients, no constant term and coefficient sum six is given by
$$(x^2 -x+1)^2(x^2+x+1)(x+1)=x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x$$
and 
$$(x^2+x+1)(x+1)x=x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 + x$$
corresponding to dice with labels $(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)$ and $(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)$.

There is no other way because each die must obtain one factor of $x$ (to have positive labels), one factor of $(x+1)$ to have even face count and one factor of $1+x+x^2$ to have face count divisible by three. Only the factors $x^2-x+1$ are "expendible".

Comment: For reference, these are known as the [Sicherman dice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicherman_dice).